# Removing elemenets from the matrix diagonals

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I want to remove the elements from main and secondary diagonal in the matrix to get a new matrix, but my code doesn't work properly.It seems that there is something wrong with the second for loop. I tried to change it, but it didn't work again. I hope you could help me.
This code should only work for even dimensions

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int m[50][50], i, j, k, n;
  printf("Dimensions: \n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
    }
  }
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
           for(k=j+1;k<n;k++){
               if(i==j)
                  m[i][k-1]=m[i][k];
               if(i+j+1==n)
                  m[i][k]=m[i][k-1];
            }
        }
    }
  printf("The new matrix: \n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n - 2; j++) {
      printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

```
// Input: 
         -69 -85   1   0
           1  -8   2 -44
          -2   5   8 -11
           1 -11   0   5
   Expected output:
         -85   1    
           1 -44  
          -2 -11  
         -11   0   
  Output of my code:
         -85   1    
         -44   2    
         -11   5    
           1 -11
```

Comment: This code is too big for this simple task. Main diagonal is just the `m[i][i]` element. The secondary can be accessed similarly with a simple modification.

Comment: In the third set of loops, when `j == 0` then `k - 2` can be `-1` which breaks the indexing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm sorry for writing everything in detail, but if I don't, people complain it's not readable

Comment: This is not in detail. You are writing a simple O(n) algorithm in O(n^2).

Comment: @WeatherVane I tried to change it to k-1, but the code still doesn't work

Comment: @EugeneSh. I wrote a shorter code, but still cannot get the correct result

Comment: How do you expect odd dimension to be handled? Example: d=3 and {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} will give ....?

Comment: @4386427 If d is odd, only main diagonal should be removed, but I managed to solve this, so I didn't want to post it as a part of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need 3 nested for-loops to do it.

You can do it with 2 nested loops. Use an extra variable to represent the destination of next element.

Try something like:

```
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        int write_index = 0;
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if (j != i && j != (n-1-i))
            {
                m[i][write_index] = m[i][j];
                ++write_index;
            }
        }
    }
```